# Is there a general way to detect if a property's type is an enumerable type?

Tags: c#

Given this:

```
class InvoiceHeader {
    public int InvoiceHeaderId { get; set; }
    IList<InvoiceDetail> LineItems { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently using this code to detect if a class has a collection property:

```
void DetectCollection(object modelSource)
{       
    Type modelSourceType = modelSource.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo p in modelSourceType.GetProperties())
    {
        if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType &&  p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a general way to detect if the LineItems is an enumerable type? Some will use other enumerable type (e.g. ICollection), not an IList.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your code doesn't actually check if the properties are `Enumerable` types but if they are generic IList's. Try this:

```
if(typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType))
{
   System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
}
```

Or this

```
if (p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(p.Name);
}
```

Comment: p.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)) && p.PropertyType != typeof(String) or otherwise a String property will pass the condigion as well

Comment: Note that not all enumerables are `IEnumerable` I believe anything with a `GetEnumerator` function can actually go in a `foreach` statement

Comment: Although it may be a little obvious, it is worth pointing out that a string is also an enumerable type. If someone is wanting to check if a property is _any_ type of list or collection, using ICollection would be much more suitable.

Comment: I can't get this to work, I'm getting `Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

Comment: In answer to my own question - I should have been using `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, not `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`.

Comment: So this results in true on a string. OK, a string is technically an array of characters, but I want to know whether it's a `string` or one of `string[]`, `IList<string>` etc...

Comment: if (prop.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEnumerable)))
                    {
                        isNULLorEmpty = ((IList)value).Count <= 0;
                    }

Comment: as it said in comments System.String is enumerable but is is single type

Answer (score 2):

```
if (invoiceHeader.LineItems is IEnumerable) {
    // LineItems implements IEnumerable
}
```

This does not work if the type of the invoiceHeader is unknown at compile time. In that case I would like to know why there isn't a common interface, because the use of reflection to find a collection property is quite dubious.

Comment: RE: "In that case I would like to know why there isn't a common interface, because the use of reflection to find a collection property is quite dubious." -- I'm making an extension library for NHibernate

Answer (score 1):

[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1x9x1b1.aspx) is the base type for all Enumerable types in C#, and thus you can check for if a property is of that type generally.

It should however be noted that C# is special in the way it binds sugar syntax (e.g. foreach loop), that it binds to methods (so for a complete check you should check if a property contains a method called GetEnumerator (Either IEnumerable.GetEnumerator or IEnumerable.GetEnumerator)

Comment: You can't simply check for `IEnumerable<T>` with reflection, as an `ICollection<T>` is exactly that to the outside, and not an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Fermaref what do you mean? `ICollection<T>` inherits from `IEnumerable`, so the `IsAssignableFrom` test should work as expected.

Comment: `is` compares an object instance with a class/structure/etc. definition. As `p.PropertyType` is of type `System.Type` and doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, it will always return `false`.

Comment: Why would I use `is`? `Type` has the `IsAssignableFrom` method that's similar to `is` but works on types.

Comment: @Femaref That is why i deleted my comment, but as CodeInChaos says IsAssignableFrom can be used instead with reflection.

Comment: because there just was a comment using the `is` keyword.

Comment: Out of interest, how would your method call look like?

Comment: @Femaref: `typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)`

Answer (score -2):

```
p.PropertyType.IsGenericType
    && p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(ICollection<>))
```

This worked for me when using Entity Framework context.

Comment: This won't work for, say, `public class Foo : List<T>`.